# Is it okay to say we or us even if you are no longer part of something?

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

I now work in marketing but I used to work in production.

How do you compare marketing to production?

Here in marketing, your suggestion gets considered. In production, they just ask us to do menial jobs such as photocopying, sorting out documents and whatnot. We don’t get to do anything great there.

Comment: *In production, they **asked us*** and ***we didn't*** *get*. If you're not there any more, and you use *we* or *they*, it needs to be in the past tense.

Answer (score 1):

If you were involved in the activities described then using "we" is correct. If you were not involved then use "they." For example:

```
When I worked for production, we didn't get to do anything great.
```

You use "we" because you were involved.

```
Since I left production, they have made significant improvements.
```

If you're no longer involved then you swap to "they."

It can get a little subjective when you are describing something that occurred with the group you're currently in at a time before you arrived. For example:

```
Even before I got here, we were doing a lot of really cool stuff.
```

Using "we" helps indicate that the speaker is looking to be associated with the people doing cool stuff. However, it wouldn't necessarily be wrong to use they in a sentence with this construction.

```
Before I arrived they were doing a lot of shady things.
```

Using "they" here works to create distance between the speaker and the group that was doing shady things, even if the speaker and the people doing shady things are now together.

Comment: So how would you rephrase my statement above?

Comment: It depends on how you want it to be read. If you want to describe how things were in the past, I'd change "ask" and "don't" to "asked" and "didn't" and keep the "we." If you want to describe how things currently are then change the "us" to a "them" and the "we" to a "they."